# Get pixel data from DICOM file .dcm

Tags: c++, dicom, dcmtk

How can i get the pixel data from .dcm file as an array variable using DCMTK library? 
I'm using [this](http://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/projects/dcmtk/wiki/Howto_AccessingCompressedData) site for preference and it didn't work, the data result is very different from the original picture.

Comment: what did you do at the end?  where it says;
 
  / Do something useful with pixData..

How did you process it next to see an image?

Answer (score 1):

The code you referenced just extracts the pixel data from the corresponding attribute. But there is much more to this. Different header elements determine how the pixel data is to be interpreted. For this, the class [DicomImage](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/classDicomImage.html) can be used. You can either use it to normalize the data to an array of (signed|unsigned) (char|short|int) using getInterData() or for rendering purposes using getOutputData().